# How to re-render a particular component in React with setInterval or there is another way?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, setinterval

I have created the functional component in React for time counter. Everything working fine. But, component is not re-rendering after every second. I am new in React.

So, how we can re-render the functional component with `setInterval()`?

```
import React from 'react'
import withStyle from 'react-jss'


const counterStyle = {
    counter:{
        color:'#FFFFFF'
    }
}

let date = new Date();    
let todayDate = date.getDate();
let hours = date.getHours()
let minutes = date.getMinutes();
let second = date.getUTCSeconds();    

const timerDisplay = () => {
     date = new Date();    
     todayDate = date.getDate();
     hours = date.getHours()
     minutes = date.getMinutes();
     second = date.getUTCSeconds();    
}

const TimeCounter = ({classes}) => {
    setInterval(() => {
        timerDisplay()
    }, 1000);
    return(
        <div className={classes.counter}>
            <h1>{`${hours} : ${minutes} : ${second} : ${todayDate}`}</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default withStyle(counterStyle)(TimeCounter);
```

Comment: look into [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to ReactJS you should definitely take a look at the [`useState` documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html#state-hook).

Your approach to a react component is wrong actually. To accomplish such simple task you can use state updates and React will automatically render the component. Without using library like momentjs, vanilla js component will look like this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import withStyle from 'react-jss'

const TimeCounter = ({classes}) => {
    const [time, setTime] = useState(new Date())

    useEffect(() => {
        setInterval(() => {
            setTime(new Date())
        }, 1000);
    }, []);

    return(
        <div className={classes.counter}>
            <h1>{`
                ${time.getHours()} : 
                ${time.getMinutes()} : 
                ${time.getUTCSeconds()} : 
                ${time.getDate()}
            `}</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default withStyle(counterStyle)(TimeCounter);
```

- I've changed global variable to state using `useState()`.
- I've used useEffect to handle "ComponentDidMount()" it will initialize an interval once.
- Just because it's state now React will listen for it's changes with `setTime()` and re-render components using that state variable.

Comment: Will this approach create a new interval each time the component is rendered?

Comment: @Camilo Yes, and it will not clear any previous intervals so it will just pile up the memory

Comment: I've just tested, indeed it is. I've updated the code sorry about that.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it is not working in my code as per my expectation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) hook to store the `date`,

```
const [timer, setTimer] = useState(new Date());
```

You must use the [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook to update the state in a interval,

```
useEffect(() => {
   const interval = setInterval(() => {
      console.log('This will run every second!');
      setTimer(new Date());
   }, 1000);

   // This is important, you must clear your interval when component unmounts
   return () => clearInterval(interval);

}, [])  // [] is for to execute `useEffect` only once as `componentWillMount`
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-52db55)

Comment: ravibagu91 which demo link you have shared that is not working.

Comment: I tried it out as soon as it was published and it was working fine.